# Proper way to store global HTTP path (Android)

Tags: android, http, global-variables

I want to store my HTTP paths in a proper way within android studio so they would not be depended on the environment (debug, compile, etc..) and not duplicated all round the project.

Would this be satisfied method, assigned in a separated class?

```
public class pathClass{
    public static final string HTTP_HOST    = "......."
    public static final string HTTP_URL     = "......."
    public static final string HTTP_METHOD  = "......."
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Best way would be store them in a separate class file as static members. So what you are doing is perfect.

Comment: People who are voting my question down, please provide with explanations why your voting down or just keep scrolling.. I cant possible know what i'm doing wrong with a vote down. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make a separate class file for your Constants and declare variable like this

public static final String LOGIN_IP = "http://1.1.17.19/demo/android_ashish_restro/login.php";

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what do you mean by saying `depended on the environment(debug, compile, etc..)`. If you want have different constants on your local machine and `CI` server for instance you can put your constants into `local.properties` file:

```
sdk.dir=/android-sdk-macosx
HTTP_METHOD="GET"
HTTP_URL="hello/path"
HTTP_HOST="google.com/"
```

And in your `build.gradle` grad it like this:

```
android{
    buildTypes{
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
            buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_HOST", properties.getProperty('HTTP_HOST')
            buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_URL", properties.getProperty('HTTP_URL')
            buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_METHOD", properties.getProperty('HTTP_METHOD')
        }
    }
}
```

Then they will be available in your java code via static constants:

```
BuildConfig.HTTP_HOST
BuildConfig.HTTP_METHOD
BuildConfig.HTTP_URL
```

If you need to have different values for `debug` and `release` versions of your app you need to define your constants in respective `buildTypes` blocks:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

        buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_HOST", properties.getProperty('HTTP_HOST_RELEASE')
        buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_URL", properties.getProperty('HTTP_URL_RELEASE')
        buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_METHOD", properties.getProperty('HTTP_METHOD_RELEASE')
    }

    debug {

        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

        buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_HOST", properties.getProperty('HTTP_HOST_DEBUG')
        buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_URL", properties.getProperty('HTTP_URL_DEBUG')
        buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_METHOD", properties.getProperty('HTTP_METHOD_DEBUG')
    }
}
```

PS And of course you can put your constants right into `build.gradle` file instead of using `local.properties` file:

```
buildConfigField "String", "HTTP_HOST", "google.com"
```